# quiero hacer un tipo carrusel de vídeos que se reproduzcan en automático

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<video preload="auto"  autoplay="autoplay" muted id="vi" controls>
</video>  </br>
```

/*agregar varios videos sin que se pierda este espacio*/

```
window.onload = function playlist(){
         var vi = document.getElementById("vi"),
                 videos = ["video1", "video2"],
                 info = document.getElementById("info");

         info.innerHTML = "video: " + videos[0];
         vi.src = videos[0] + ".mp4";
         vi.play();

         if (vi.ended)
                    function next() {
                             var nombreActual = info.innerHTML.split(": ")[1];
                             var actual = videos.indexOf(nombreActual);
                             this.src = (actual == videos.length - 1 ? videos[0] : videos[actual + 1]) + ".mp4";
                             info.innerHTML = "video: " + videos[actual + 1];
                             this.play();
                    };
}
</script>
```

/Tengo esta función pero quiero que al detectar que sea reproducido el ultimo vídeo reproduzca de nuevo el primer vídeo y que se haga hasta que se cierre la pagina/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea la tienes, pero la verdad te falta pulir un poco más.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear un ***carrusel*** de videos, que se reproduzcan continuamente hasta que la página se recargue (y por ende vuelve a empezar), se cierre o el usuario pare la reproducción.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, vamos a crear 2 métodos y [añadiremos un `eventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) a nuestro video.

El primer método lo llamaremos `playVideo(video, player)`, y su función será establecer el atributo `src` del objeto `player` y ejecutar el método `play()`, además actualizará la etiqueta de información del video que se está reproduciendo.

El segundo método lo llamaremos `initVideoPlayer()`, y como su nombre sugiere iniciará el reproductor de video con los parámetros que consideremos necesarios, entre ellos el valor del video inicial, y le agregaremos el evento `ended` al objeto `player`.

**playVideo(video, player)**

Este método tomará como argumentos el nombre del archivo de video a ser reproducido y el objeto `player` que se encargará de reproducir el video.

```
const playVideo = (video, player) => {
    player.src = video;
    player.play();
    info.innerHTML = 'Video: ' + video;
}
```

**initVideoPlayer()**

Este método lo llamaremos cuando el documento se haya cargado totalmente. Usaremos una variable `current` para almacenar el valor del índice de la lista de videos. Y una variable `video` que almacenará el nombre del archivo correspondiente al índice de la lista de videos. Además, usaremos el método `addEventListener` para añadir el evento `ended` al objeto `player`.

Cuando el evento `ended` ocurra, se ejecutará una función que actualizará el valor de `current` y el valor de `video` y llamará a la función `playVideo()` pasandole los valores actualizados como argumento.

El truco está en capturar el valor de `current` y establecerlo a `0` si se ha alcanzado el último valor de la lista de videos disponibles, con esto la reproducción empezará nuevamente desde el primer elemento de dicha lista.

```
const initVideoPlayer = () => {
  let current = 0; // <- En la primera ejecución establecemos el valor al primer video de la lista
  let video = Videos[current]; // <- establecemos el nombre del archivo
  if(!video) return; // <- si la lista está vacía salimos, no hay nada a reproducir
  playVideo(video, player); // <- reproducimos el primer video
  player.addEventListener('ended', (e) => { // <- añadimos un eventListener para el evento ended
    current++; // <- incrementamos el indice
    if(current === Videos.length) { // <- si el indice alcanza el valor maximo
      current = 0; // <- volvemos a poner indice a cero
    }
    video = Videos[current]; // <- establecemos el nombre del archivo
    playVideo(video, player); // <- ejecutamos playVideo con los datos nuevos
  });
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos una forma de reproducir la lista de videos de principio a fin y volver a empezar cuando se reproduzca el último video de la lista.

Un ejemplo de funcionamiento muy básico sería el siguiente:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const Videos = [
    'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4',
    'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4',
    'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4',
    ];
  const player = document.getElementById('player');
  const info = document.getElementById('info');
  
  const playVideo = (video, player) => {
    player.src = video;
    player.play();
    info.innerHTML = 'Video: ' + video;
  }
  
  const initVideoPlayer = () => {
    let current = 0;
    let video = Videos[current];
    if(!video) return;
    playVideo(video, player);
    player.addEventListener('ended', (e) => {
      current++;
      if(current === Videos.length) {
        current = 0;
      }
      video = Videos[current];
      playVideo(video, player);
    });
  }
  
  initVideoPlayer();
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id="info"></div>
  <br>
  <video preload="auto" id="player" width="360" height="240" autoplay muted controls>
  </video>
</center>
```

Con esto ya tienes la funcionalidad básica del carrusel que se ejecuta indefinidamente. Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te ayude a solventar el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que planteas la necesidad de seguir reproduciendo los videos de la lista en caso de que alguno de ellos no estuviera disponible, te presentaré una solución sencilla.

Vamos a añadir un `eventListener` para el evento `error` del objeto `player`, de la siguiente manera:

```
player.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
  // el contenido de esta función será el mismo que el de
  // la función para el evento ended.
});
```

Dado que las funciones que manejan los eventos son iguales, vamos a crear una función que se llamará `playNext()` para no repetir el código en cada evento.

Una forma en la que nuestro carrusel puede quedar sería la siguiente:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const Videos = [
    'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4',
    'este-video-no-existe.mp4',
    'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4',
    'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4',
    'este-otro-video-tampoco-existe.mp4',
    ];
  const player = document.getElementById('player');
  const info = document.getElementById('info');
  
  const playVideo = (video, player) => {
    player.src = video;
    player.play();
    info.innerHTML = 'Video: ' + video;
  }
  
  const initVideoPlayer = () => {
    let current = 0;
    let video = Videos[current];
    if(!video) return;
    playVideo(video, player);
    
    const playNext = (event) => {
      current++;
      if(current === Videos.length) {
        current = 0;
      }
      video = Videos[current];
      playVideo(video, player);
    }
    
    player.addEventListener('ended', playNext);
    player.addEventListener('error', playNext);
  }
  
  initVideoPlayer();
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id="info"></div>
  <br>
  <video preload="auto" id="player" width="360" height="240" autoplay muted controls>
  </video>
</center>
```

Como puedes apreciar, he agregado dos entradas a la lista de videos, las cuales causan un error al intentar reproducirse. Pero dado que he añadido una función que se ejecuta en el evento `error`, la reproducción continúa al siguiente video de la lista.

Espero que esto resuelva tu duda.

Comment: Gracias excelente tu solución en realidad me sirvió ya tenia algo funcionando pero menos eficiente.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar a que no truene cuando un vídeo no exista y que reproduzca el que sigue

Comment: Por supuesto, ya edito la respuesta.

Comment: @ContrerasAngel, puedes revisar la edición a la respuesta, espero que sea lo que buscas. Saludos

Comment: si ya lo estuve probando de diferentes maneras y funciona bien.